# cut off part of catchment

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, line

I want to edit a polygon as that I cut off a part of it. I want to freely make a line that define where the polygon should be seperated. I have tried to useedit vertices but it does not seem to be a good tool for the purpose.

I use ArcGis 10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key for me was to find Create Features under editor windows. Here I could draw the polygon of which the catchment should be cut by.